# Synchronized Implementation of a Business Logic

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

**Implement using existing Synchronized Java classes (Hashtable, StringBuffer, Vector)**

or

**synchronize the blocks when we implement Unsynchronized Java classes (HashMap, StringBuilder, ArrayList)**

or

**create a synchronized collection objects from Collections.synchronizedXXX() method and then use it** (of course, i cant synchronize StringBuilder like this.!!)

In a multi-threaded scenario, which of the above will be the best way to achieve synchronization without any performance kill?

Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: StringBuilder is not synchronized, StringBuffer is synchronized.

Comment: thank you for bringing it to notice.. +1 for you..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach depends on exactly what your code is trying to do and the level of atomicity you require. Sometimes the `Collections.synchronizedWhatever` is fine; sometimes you need to do your own synchronization.

In terms of performance you just need to make sure you minimise the number of `synchronized` blocks that are entered. There will be little difference between

```
(example A)
List l = Collections.synchronizedList(originalList);
l.add(something);
```

and

```
(example B)
synchronized (originalList) {
    originalList.add(something);
}
```

because they both enter one synchronized block. However:

```
(example C)
List l = Collections.synchronizedList(originalList);
l.add(something);
int index = l.indexOf(something);
```

will enter two synchronized blocks, whereas

```
(example D)
synchronized (originalList) {
    originalList.add(something);
    int index = originalList.indexOf(something);
}
```

will only enter one synchronized block. Of course it spends longer in that block so it may increase contention, but the add and the indexOf now behave like a single atomic operation. This may or may not be what you want: it's entirely application dependent.

EDIT: To answer Deepak's question:

The 'synchronizedList' in example C means that each call to a method on 'l' will be wrapped inside a synchronized block. You can think of C as doing this:

```
synchronized (originalList) {
    originalList.add(something);
}
synchronized (originalList) {
    int index = originalList.indexOf(something);
}
```

There is some added cost here, but unless it's in a performance-critical section of your code it's probably not going to be a problem. I'd suggest you think more about ensuring your code behaves correctly before you think about optimising it. It's hard to get thread-safe code right so be very careful with how you write things. For example, in C there is a possible race condition between 'l.add(something)' and 'l.indexOf(something)'. D does not have the same race condition because both operations are inside a single synchronized block.

Brian Goetz's book (Java Concurrency in Practice) is an excellent resource for learning how to write thread-safe code. I highly recommend it. I'm sure it's on Amazon.

Comment: thank you for your reply.! Single synchronized lock with many operations will take more time or many operations on a internally synchronized object will take more time?

Comment: Could you explain in brief how there are 2 synchrnized blocks and how there is a single synchronized block in above cited example code of yours.Please reply.Could you provide us with a code which demonstrates performance in above 2 cases

Comment: @Radkrish: Entering or leaving a synchronized block is fairly expensive so it's best to minimise them. Doing 10 operations inside one synchronized block will be faster than doing the same 10 operations if they each enter and leave a block.

Comment: @Deepak: Updated the answer. While it's true that entering/leaving synchronized blocks is relatively expensive it's not something you should bother optimising unless you really need to. It's also very difficult to optimise because it's easy to introduce race conditions and to create nasty contention issues.